# Distance of identity from $\left\{f \in C[0,1] \: : \: \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}f(t) dt = f(0) \right\}$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

Consider the space $C[0,1]$ with $\sup$ norm. One can ask what is the distance of $$\mathrm{id}_{[0,1]}(x)=x$$ from its closed subspace $$\left\{f \in C[0,1] \:  : \: \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}f(t) dt = f(0) \right\}.$$

My only idea is to compute it from the definition, yet it does not look pleasant nor computable so I would be grateful for suggestions of clever observations ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If identity means the characteristic function of $[0,1]$

Answer:1/3

For any $\epsilon>0$, one can set $f$ to be $4/3$ on everywhere except a small neighborhood of $0$, and $f(0)=2/3-\epsilon$, accordingly. So, the distance is less then $1/3+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$. Thus, the maximum possible value is $1/3$.

Let $f$ be a function in your set with distance to the identity equal to $u$. Then, 
$$1-u\le f(0)=\int_0^{1/2}f(t)dt\le (1+u)\frac12$$
implies $u\ge 1/3$. So, the answer is $1/3$

### If identity means $x\mapsto x$

Answer:1/12

For any $\epsilon>0$, one can set $f$ to be $x-1/12$ on everywhere except a small neighborhood of $0$, and $f(0)=1/12+\epsilon$, accordingly. So, the distance is less than $1/12+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$. Thus, the maximum possible value is $1/12$.

Let $f$ be a function in your set with distance to the identity equal to $u$. Then, 
$$u\ge f(0)= \int_0^{1/2}f(t)dt\ge -\frac u2+\int_0^{1/2}tdt=-\frac u2+\frac18$$
implies $u\ge 1/12$. So, the answer is $1/12$

Comment: What if $f(x)=x+1/4$ its integral is $2*1/8=1/4=f(0)$ but $|x-f(x)|=1/4<1/3$ maybe i missed something with the norm?

Comment: The identity is the constant function that is equal to $1$ everywhere.

Comment: Please,excuse my slowness but is it in this specific case that the identity is the constant? I checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function as a second opinion.Thanks for your time

Comment: As I'm not the OP, I'm not sure. But, I've seen the word "identity" to be used to refer both functions. It might be $f(x)=x$, but the same solution would work for $f(x)=x$, also.

Comment: @Alan246 I edited the solution to cover the case you mentioned.

Comment: Let $g(x)=x-1/12$ since $f$ and $g$ only "disagree" in a set of zero measure their integral must be equal (over same interval). But then again integrating $g$ i get $1/12\neq g(0)=-1/12$ (then it wouldnt fit the conditions) how do i set this apparently discontinuity of  $f(x)$ next to zero?

Comment: @Emre I would appriciate if you expand your considerations since they are highly unclear. Firstely the distance of function you are considering in first paragrph equal $1/12- \epsilon$ in 0 and $x-1/12$ except neigh. of $0$ may be farer from identity than $\epsilon + 1/12$ since you may be force to make it smaller than $- 1/12$ in neigh. of $0$ in order to stay in our subspace.

Comment: Let $f(x)=x-1/12$ on $[\delta,1]$. On $[0,\delta]$ make $f$ linear such that $f(0)=1/12+\epsilon$ and $f(\delta)=\delta-1/12$. This map decreasing on $[0,\delta]$ so, for any $y\in[0,\delta]$, $f(y)\ge \delta-1/12\ge y-1/12$ and $y+1/12+\epsilon\ge 1/12+\epsilon\ge f(0)\ge f(y)$. Thus, its distance to th identity is $1/12+\epsilon$. Moreover, as $\delta\to 0$, the integral goes to $1/12$, thus, $\delta$ can be chosen such that $f(0)=\int_0^{1/2}f(t)dt$.